# Agregar un identificador en un Id

Tags: php, html5

Tengo este código, que ya tiene un identificador de ordenes de pedidos que usa el color verde si ya se le registro un pedido y azul si no se registrado aún, pero ahora necesito que me pueda identificar un control de calidad pero esta vez que use el un asterisco *.

> **Ejemplo con Identificador de ordenes de pedidos 1**

```
public function read(){
            for($i=0; $i <COUNT($objData); $i++) {
                $objData[$i]->setDnp($this->Ordenpedido($objData[$i]->getId()));
            }
        }
```

> **Ejemplo con Identificador de ordenes de pedidos 2**

```
public function Ordenpedido($id){
            
            $pedidos = LensesOrderDAOImp::getInstance()->getAll("0,1", "ordenp_id = $id");
            if(empty($pedidos)){
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }
        }
```

> **Ejemplo con Identificador de ordenes de pedidos 3**

```
    if(in_array(25,$permisosF)){
                    if($this->Ordenpedido($item->getId())){
                        $color = '#22B61D';
                    }else{
                        $color = 'blue';
                    }
    $respuesta.= "<td><a class='modalPedidoLentes' data-toggle='modal' data-target='.modal-pedido-lentes' data-idOrder='" . $item->getId() . "'
    data-url='". getUrl("Sales","PurchaseOrder","LensesOrder",FALSE,"ajax") ."' style='cursor:pointer;color:$color;'>" . $item->getId() . "</a></td>";
```

se ve de esta manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora lo que yo necesito es que cuando agrego un control de calidad me pueda aparecer un asterisco * en los Id que le han registrado un control de calidad, a mi me instruyeron que tenia que hacer exactamente lo mismo que ordenes de pedidos pero aun no logro.

Comment: y como determinas que un Id se le ha registrado un control de calidad? haciendo llamado a que funcion o validando que propiedad?

Comment: Falta un detalle esencial para el problema que nos planteas: ¿de qué modo están persistiendo los datos? ¿qué herramientas usas? Si es una base de datos, en la instrucción SQL vas a identificar los Ids que pasaron control de calidad y en la lectura de los datos podrás poner o no el asterisco.